# sum.swift:29:19: error: cannot find 'CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent' in scope

Tags: swift

I am trying to calculate the execution time of my swift program. I'm trying to use `CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()`, but I'm getting an error: `sum.swift:29:19: error: cannot find 'CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent' in scope`

I saw that on Mac this can be resolved by restarting Xcode, however I'm using Linux and can't find any solution to this.

Here's my complete code

```swift
import Foundation

// User prompt
print("Enter a digit between 0 and 9:", terminator: " ")
// readLine() returns optional string
let input1: String? = readLine()

// User prompt
print("Enter another digit between 0 and 9:", terminator: " ")
// readLine() returns optional string
let input2: String? = readLine()

// Recording execution Time
let startTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
// Converting String input to Int
if let n1 = Int(input1!), // Checking if optional String can be converted to Int
    let n2 = Int(input2!),// Checking if optional String can be converted to Int
    n1 >= 0 && n1 <= 9,   // Checking if it's single digit
    n2 >= 0 && n2 <= 9 {  // Checking if it's single digit
        print("Sum: \(n1+n2)")
    } else {
        preconditionFailure("Input conditions not met!!")       
}
let timeElapsed = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - startTime
print("Time elapsed: \(timeElapsed) s.")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by importing `CoreFoundation`.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up here because I typed `var start: CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent?` and got error `Cannot find type 'CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent' in scope`. And what a surprise CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent is a func (`func CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() -> CFAbsoluteTime`). So if you want to use type then it's CFAbsoluteTime. May be useful for someone..